# Integrating django apps in your own views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Let's say I'm writing a complex site in django with wikis, forums, ... or writing my own apps that I intend to reuse from different sites.

I really want to create, for example, a wiki page that has a forum at the bottom, or reuse my previously written wiki app with a different graphical layout.

What is the best way to structure my app to allow this kind of reuse?

So far, I have been giving apps their own urls in urls.py. This however does not work if I want to combine multiple apps together in a single page.

Additionally, most of the apps I found online come with their own templates, which has the full html, and do not separate the logic of creating / preparing a context from that of handling a request and generating a reply.

What is the best practice here? What do you do? edit the templates that come from applications you download online? refactor them to fit in your application?

what should I do for my own applications? structure them so they have a method to get the context, and a method to render it?

Answer (score 0):

Django hasn't great support out of the box to component-oriented architectures. I find this problematic some times too. You'll face to problems here.

1. Architecture
2. Code

**Architecture:** As Django is not component oriented, all the apps aren't component oriented neither. The designers and coders for those apps haven't thought about that. So they've just built "views" to interface with their apps. You'll need to get something more "pluggable".

**Code:** Once you decide to build that, you'll have to find what support you have for that. Most Django apps are pretty well coded, so you won't have much code in views, but abstracted in other places. That way you could reuse that code and build your own components.

**Example:** Suppose you're working with a third-party Wiki app. That wiki has a view to display  highest ranked Tags and other view to create a wiki entry. If the code is good enough (that I'm assuming it is because Django has a pretty good community), you could refactor that to use components. The view to create an entry must be using some Form, that you can plug in your own site. And the view to get highest ranked tags probably uses some utility function, or some Tag manager's method. In that case you could refactor it to your own needs.

Hope it helps.